# Does React need to Re-Render Textbox at its OnChange Event

Tags: reactjs

I've been working on a React project recently. I've gotten to the point where I know that when typing in a textbox React updates its UI state and re-renders the textbox and brings focus back to it. The whole process happens so fast that user doesn't notice that textbox has been re-rendered while typing.

Now here my question is that why doesn't React just update UI state of textbox at onChange event and doesn't re-render the textbox and hence doesn't require to put focus on it.

Why isn't the re-render process saved in this, or other similar, cases. What were we missing if we dont re-render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't re-render elements in the sense that it creates a new one which replaces the old. In your example it simply updates the value.

React will only ever *remove* an element if it was replaced with one of another type. If it's of the same type, it will simply update the missing or altered attributes. You should have a read about [**Reacts Reconciliation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) on the official docs.

> #### Elements Of Different Types
>
> Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch. Going from `<a>` to `<img>`, or from `<Article>` to `<Comment>`, or from `<Button>` to `<div>` - any of those will lead to a full rebuild.
>
> ---
>
> #### DOM Elements Of The Same Type
>
> When comparing two React DOM elements of the same type, React looks at the attributes of both, keeps the same underlying DOM node, and only updates the changed attributes.

---

## Demo

I have prepared a demo below. It's a combination of React with jQuery just to demonstrate this.

- When you type some text into the textarea, the state is updated and the element value is updated to show what you typed. This is done with React.
- The button is *outside* the React scope completely. There is an eventlistener written with jQuery which randomly alters the elements css background color.

If the component was **replaced** each time React updated the state value of the component (*i.e when we type inside the textarea*), the background color would be lost since we would be talking about a newly created DOM element.

However, as you can see, this is **not the case** -- the background stays.

```js
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {txt: ""};
  }
  
  updateTextarea = (e) => {
    this.setState({txt: e.target.value});
  }
  
  render() {
    return <textarea onChange={this.updateTextarea}>{this.state.txt}</textarea>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById('app'));

$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var colors = ["red", "green", "lightblue", "grey", "pink", "orange"];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $("#app textarea").css("background", colors[rand]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
<button id="btn">Randomize color!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris, that was spot on and is what I was looking for.