# React renders again the same div elements - Reconciliation question

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React documentation I was reading about [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm). The following interesting scenario just came to my mind.

In my examples the code uses a `button` element to toggle a `boolean` value on click event. Based on that the code decides with ternary operator which element should React render.

Let's have two components to represent my example:

```
const First = () => {
    return <div>element - no difference</div>
}

const Second = () => {
    return <div>element - no difference</div>
}
```

There are no difference in the rendered elements at the end.

**First example**

Have `First` and `Second` functional components in the first example as the following:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
    const [renderFirst, setRenderFirst] = useState(true);

    return <>
        <button onClick={() => setRenderFirst(!renderFirst)}>Toggle</button>
        {renderFirst ? <First /> : <Second /> }
    </>
}
```

**Second example**

In the second example just using `div` elements but ending with the same results:

```
const Contact = () => {
    const [renderFirst, setRenderFirst] = useState(true);

    return <>
        <button onClick={() => setRenderFirst(!renderFirst)}>Toggle</button>
        {renderFirst ? <div>element - no difference</div> : <div>element - no difference</div> }
    </>
}
```

**Question**

My understanding as per the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types) states:

> Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch.

At the end in either way the rendered result will end up `<div>element - no difference</div>`. The **Second example** is not rendering again the DOM element obviously.

Why is React rendering the **First example** then? Are those considered different types in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *rendering* I assume you mean changes to be "rendered" aka *committed* to the DOM. The reconciliation process will still be triggered in both examples.

The answer is simple. In your first example you are returning a React *component* (`<First />` or `<Second />`) whereas in the second example you are returning a React *element* (one of the two `div`'s).

React cannot know beforehand what each of your two components will do (they could have their own logic), so in the latter case, React will just see that you want to replace `First` with `Second` and just re-render. In the former case, you are only returning **elements** which can be objectively compared.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? Can the downvoter please clarify what's bad about this answer?

Comment: I believe OP's assumptions are wrong, in both cases, the DOM is rendered again, at least if you can prove otherwise. Therefore, I think that claiming that the examples are different is wrong.

Comment: @DennisVash, by "rendering" I believe OP meant changes to be commited to the DOM. The reconciliation process will still be triggered of course since the state variable has changed. However, in the second example, the `div` "instance" will not change - the div will remain. In the first example, the previous `div` will be replaced with an identical, but new one.

Comment: Please prove that "However, in the second example, the div "instance" will not change - the div will remain." is a fact. As far as I checked, there is a different instance.

Comment: @DennisVash sure, here is a quick fork https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-itb6h. Inspect the `div` and set, for example `color: red`, then toggle the element - the style remains. Now render instead `Contact2` and do the same - the element is replaced with a new `div` and the style disappears.

Comment: @DennisVash I knew I had answered this before. It took me a few, but I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856011/2030321 seems relevant.

Comment: Thank you for verifying it, what I was trying to do is comparing the children on render and made a small bug, now my example works. https://codesandbox.io/s/q-58859121-sameinstace-96usm

Comment: @DennisVash indeed, and that's a cleaner test too :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58859376/7882470) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856011/2030321), I made a small test approving the answer.

My main consideration was if `JSX` will generate a new instance although the components may unmounted due to the condition.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// You can check either
const Component = <div>element - no difference</div>;

const Contact = () => {
  const [renderFirst, setRenderFirst] = useState(true);
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const first = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(componentRef.current);

    const [child] = componentRef.current.children;

    if (!first.current) {
      first.current = child;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const [child] = componentRef.current.children;
    console.log(child !== first.current ? 'different' : 'same');
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setRenderFirst(prev => !prev)}>Toggle</button>
      <div ref={componentRef}>
        {renderFirst ? (
          <div>element - no difference</div>
        ) : (
          <div>element - no difference</div>
        )}
        {/* {renderFirst ? Component : Component} */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Contact />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-58859121-SameInstace]